# Check if data exist in gridview Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm attempting to check a gridview if a id number exist and throws at an error message otherwise add the data to the gridview. This is what I have so far; I get the error message but also add to the gridview at the sametime. Data is being pulled from another gridview.

```
int row = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
    String val = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text.ToString();

    foreach (GridViewRow rows in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            //String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            String cellText = rows.Cells[i].Text;
            if (val == cellText)
            {
                lblError.Text = "ID number already assigned!!";
            }


        }

    }
    if (GridView2.Rows.Count >= 0)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();


        dr["StudentName"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Text;
        dr["IDNum"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text;


        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Comment: you can use a variable "flag", so when you set the error message set flag = true; also, and chage the if to if (GridView2.Rows.Count >= 0 && flag = false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add boolean error flag like this:

```
int row = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
String val = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text.ToString();

bool errorFound = false;

foreach (GridViewRow rows in GridView2.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        //String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        String cellText = rows.Cells[i].Text;
        if (val == cellText)
        {
            errorFound = true;
            lblError.Text = "ID number already assigned!!";
        }
    }
}

if (GridView2.Rows.Count >= 0 && !errorFound)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["StudentName"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Text;
    dr["IDNum"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in the code.

First: You have ID values being displayed in the 2nd column of the grid and still you are looping thru all the columns just to compare the ID number.

You can avoid inner for loop.

Second : Also once you find out that the ID number already exist in the gridview, you should break out of the loop. There is no point in going thru all the other rows once you know that the ID exist.

Third : Once you are out of the foreach loop, you just compare the number of rows in the GridView against 0 and try to add row to gridview. But actually what you need to check if there is an ID found in the foreach loop. And if it is found you should not add row to grid view.

So your code look like as following.

```
int row = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;

String val = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
bool idFound = false;
foreach (GridViewRow rows in GridView2.Rows)
{
    //Get the Text of 2nd Cell in cellText Variable.
    String cellText = rows.Cells[1].Text;
    if (val == cellText)
    {
        //Display error message and set idFound value to true.
        lblError.Text = "ID number already assigned!!";
        idFound = true;
    }
}

//Check value of idFound, if it is false then add row to GridView1
if (!idFound)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["StudentName"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Text;
    dr["IDNum"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```